# clients still want lower screen iphone tabs on android, solution?

Tags: android, iphone, user-interface, tabs, user-experience

clients want exact replica app on iphone and android. the iphone design is the only one thought about, and it frequently has tabs on the lower part of the screen

in android, this can be replicated but the primary way of doing this was deprecated, for various reasons. (tabhost, tab groups, activity) android's replacement methods include `action bars` and `viewpagers` and `fragments` with a varying degree of backwards compatibility but they don't really put the resulting tabs at the bottom of the screen.

similarly, multiplatform web app tools like Sencha Touch can generate intuitive "bottom tabs" on both platforms. So for Android there are still a variety of ways to do bottom tabs, so it would be fiction to tell a client that they **need** to change their iphone design for android

how do developers and consultants approach this. any best practices?

Comment: Tell then it is your expert opinion that users prefer platform specific UI design, and maybe show them excerpts from http://developer.android.com/design/  If they still insist on having an iPhone UI, you can't do much but comply and silently laugh as their App is downvoted.

Comment: Alternatively tell them it cost extra and charge them as such and create a custom tab layout with radio buttons or similar.

Comment: blunt but android users dont mind lower screen icons, or visual back buttons. I used to push for removing icon "back" buttons from android designs, but turns out a lot of technophones don't know anything about their android's back button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite know what you're asking for.  If it's a programming solution, then someone who's made bottom tabs before could answer.  I've never done it, so I don't know if there's an easier way than the brute force do-it-yourself approach.

If it's a consultation answer, then the best approach that's worked for me is to convince the client that the "Android way" is to put tabs on the top. As such, people who use Android phones regularly come to expect a certain way things are done.  Especially since ICS came out, soft buttons have been moved to the bottom of the screen.  These can't be shifted, moved, or removed and having tabs on the bottom could result in the user accidentally pressing either back, home, or process-list.

Comment: the tabs issue has been evolving with android over the past two years, so this isn't exactly a timeless question for someone that has done tabs at any point in the past. its more so that its 2012: how do people approach this situation right now since newer versions of android are actually used in the population